# How to use VSCode to view the source code for a Rust dependency?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I have a database table that causes error like "the trait diesel:Expression is not implemented for" when using Diesel, so I would like to identify the cause from source code. However, VS Code does not show dependency in the "Explorer" tab by default.

How can I navigate through dependency source files using VSCode?

Comment: `ctrl` + `click on definition`?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you merely want to explore the source code of the crates you depend on? Or do you actually want to solve the error? If what you want is to solve the error and get your code working, then you should change the title and ask a different question.

Comment: @DMaster I solved the error. I want to explore the source code.

Comment: @Netwave compiling error gives the name, but nowhere in the package. So cannot click on the definition

Comment: @Tiina but it will give you the error line in your code where you use something from the lib right>?

Comment: @Netwave it did not give any clue in the code. I guess it has something to do with the macro, like `some_table!`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to `ctrl` + `click` or `Go to Definition` for an element from a dependency to view its source, you need to have the `rust-analyzer` extension on VS Code.

[image]

If you really want to navigate the files in particular, you'll be able to see the filepath of the source at the top of the code window after visiting a definition from that crate.